# OK to ask a series of related, but specific questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm starting on a seemingly straightforward project that has led to multiple questions. [My first question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94737/is-it-safe-and-within-code-1970-us-to-permanently-wire-a-20-cord-to-a-garage) led to a [second question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94747/can-i-transition-from-aluminum-wiring-to-copper-wiring-at-a-co-alr-receptacle) and I was about to post a third question. I decided to stop and ask Meta for guidance.

Each question is very specific. I want to ask narrow, objectively answerable questions about each step of a project rather than a broad subjective question about the entire project.

Is asking multiple questions the correct approach here?

Comment: I absolutely think this is the better way. Bonus points whenever you ensure the question will also help future googlers who work on similar project. (That strongly involves choosing a good title)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

Each question should be about one specific problem (with the necessary background) otherwise it runs the risk of being too broad.

There's nothing wrong with posting a follow-up question, but it's probably best to wait until you've got an answer on the previous one first. After all the answer could have a material impact on the question you want to ask next. I'll try to illustrate with a trivial example.

> Q1. How do I lay a concrete slab on this site?
>
> Q2. How do I fix a shed to the concrete slab?

At first glance it would appear to be OK to ask question 2 at the same time as question 1, but if the answer is say:

> The slope is too steep to take a concrete slab, you need to build a platform.

Then the second question is redundant.

Comment: It'd be nice to know that you're putting a shed on the new slab, I might advise you embed some threaded rod to tie down the footers. They should be separate questions, but with a quick overview on each, and probably linked.

Comment: @Mazura Well I did say it was an example ;) But yes, you need to give as much information as possible